# redirection firewalls symfony 4

Tags: symfony, google-plus, symfony4, firewall

Hello I have an issue on login operation when for more explain , have 2 button :

- sign in (with email and password)
- login with gmail accout 
  when i click write email and password , click on sign in is redirect me to chose an gmail account but i want to login with email and password normaly

and this is security.yaml file

**security.yaml**

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: argon2i

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false   
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

        logout: 
            path: logout 
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
      - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
      - { path: ^/car, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

how resolve this problem

Comment: which problem ?

Comment: Is when clicking on sign in mean simple login using email and password is redirecting always on google auth but I resolve it is because I'm writing an action inside login form redirecting me to google and I forget that I writing before